# using session variables in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, session

I am trying to use Laravel session variable to store a user's viewing mode which should toggle when the user clicks on a button. I created a route for this. For some reason the session variable is not being persisted accross the whole app.

Take a look at my code. This is the method in my controller accessed via a link:

```
public function changeQuoteViewModeAjax(Request $request)
{
    $mode = $request->session()->get('mode');

    if($mode == 'private') {
        $request->session()->put('mode', 'public');
    } else {
        $request->session()->put('mode', 'private');
    }
    if($request->session()->has('mode')) {
        print_r(json_encode([
            'success' => true,
            'mode' => $request->session()->get('mode')
        ]));

        die();
    }
}
```

When I visit this link I constantly get a printed output that the view mode is private. This is because the `$mode` variable in the beginning is always empty. I am not sure why this is. 
Any help much appreciated

Comment: I think that might be because you `die();`, causing the session to *not* be saved to disk.

Comment: Session data is written terminably.. This means that it is not actually placed in storage until the response has been sent to the browser; this is why `die()` is stopping it.

Comment: if thats not your issue could you mention which session driver you are using?